# How to make the button_Click event opens the page in a pop-up window in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

The question is simple but I can't find a simple answer to it! .. btw I'll need to pass a QueryString to the page to be open.

Any ideas ?

Comment: this probably answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309979/asp-net-webforms-postback-then-open-popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually link a javascript code into .NET with C#, below is an example, you could replace with your info, and push the parameters.

```
   Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('Page.aspx?ID=" + YourTextField.Text.ToString() + "','_blank');</script>");
```

You can append on the end of it ?Field=your value passing&nextField=another value.

Comment: I think this might work but how to implement this on the event of click for an asp:button ?

Comment: Really sorry Amit for the late feedback, I appreciate your help a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer to do this in javascript.  As you make the underlying page in asp.net, provide it with the javascript to catch the buttons onclick event and call window.open(URL)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do but the simplest is to use the `OnClientClick` property of the `Button`. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k.aspx, in particular the details bout this property a little bit down.

Basically you'd do something like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" 
        OnClientClick="ShowPopup();" 
        Text="Test Client Click" />
```

With the JS to do your popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
        window.open('ThankYou.aspx');
    }
</script>
```

You can also do both an `OnClientClick` and an `OnClick` if you need as well.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" 
      OnClick="Button1_Click" 
        OnClientClick="ShowPopup();" 
        Text="Test Client Click" />
```

Code behind

```
    protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Server click handler called.";
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "this property a little bit down." .. and how can I pass a QueryString to the popup ?

Comment: I meant a little bit down on the MSDN link. Look in the **To add a client onclick event to a button control** section. Also, where are you getting the query string from details? If you're trying to get a result from the `OnClick` event and pass that to a pop-up, you'll need to take a different approach and either figure out the details manually in the popup or what AmitApollo said and Response.Write it after the postback.